# Count overlapping results of (several) MySQL-queries

Tags: mysql, select, count, resultset

I'd like to run 3 different SELECT queries on a MySQL database:

The Database Contains the following entries:

```
Rio      SouthAmerica
Rio      startsWithR
Rio      endsWithO
Rome     Europe
Rome     startsWithR
Rome     endsWithE
Curitiba SouthAmerica
Curitiba startsWithC
Curitiba endsWithA
Recife   SouthAmerica
Recife   startsWithR
Recife   endsWithE
```

Now I execute the following queries

```
SELECT city FROM db.tab WHERE tag="SouthAmerica"
/*Result: Rio, Curitiba, Recife */
SELECT city FROM db.tab WHERE tag="startsWithR"
/*Result: Rio, Recife, Rome */
SELECT city FROM db.tab WHERE tag="endsWithO"
/*Result: Rio */
```

Now I'd like to count, how often a city was returned as a result of those queries. I could do it by iterating over the results, but I'm convinced there is a better way. Can I do it with a single query? Or do I need nested queries? I like to get the result:

```
Rio      3
Recife   2
Curitiba 1
Rome     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `union all` and aggregation:

```
SELECT city, count(*)
FROM ((SELECT city FROM db.tab WHERE tag="SouthAmerica"
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT city FROM db.tab WHERE tag="startsWithR"
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT city FROM db.tab WHERE tag="endsWithO"
      )
     ) c
GROUP BY city;
```

Actually, I notice that all three subqueries are from the same table.  So, just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT city, sum(tag in ('SouthAmerica', 'startsWithR', 'endsWithO'))
FROM db.tab
GROUP BY city;
```

Or, alternatively

```
SELECT city, count(*)
FROM db.tab
WHERE tag in ('SouthAmerica', 'startsWithR', 'endsWithO')
GROUP BY city;
```